# Should I do unit tests for the same application targeted on two different version of .NET?

Tags: .net, tdd

**Here is a bit of context:**

I am practicing TDD for a new application that will target .NET 3.5 CF and .NET 4.5.2 FF.

I might have some part of the code that use polymorphisme to decide at run-time a strategy (the design pattern) to use while running on a .NET 3.5 CF machine and an another running on a .NET 4.5.2 FF machine. Both version are in different solution and code files are added as links as to not "duplicate the code". This is out of my control since it was a corporate decision made above me and I have to live with it.

**My question is:**

Should I add a test project to both the FF version and the CF version (by adding the test cases files as links in the CF solution to be able to run these in CF) or if everything is tested in FF I can assume the CF half is OK?

**Note:**

I know the "two solutions" part might not be the best way to go, but this is what I have to work with.

Comment: Do you know that .NET 4.5 can run .NET 3.5 code?

Comment: @Hosch250 Yes I know, but the production environnement cannot run .NET 4.5. I have 2 production environnement one in 4.5, the other in 3.5. I have build scripts that builds the project and run the tests for both. But I was wondering if I had to run the tests for my 3.5 script. But just as Bart van Ingen Schenau said in is answer I will do the 3.5 tests only if the risk is high enough.

Comment: @Sebastien what Hosch (and I) are saying is that 4.5 can run 3.5 code. There would really have to be a *very* compelling reason to compile against 4.5. You can run your 3.5 version in the 4.5 environment.

Comment: To that point, if you're doomed to link code files like this, you're much more at risk to break the 3.5 code with features that are only available in 4.5. *Test the 3.5 code* if you can only afford to test one.

Comment: Just write a single 3.5 version.  It will run in 4.5 just the same.

Comment: Why you want support different .NET version for whole application. Applications are bounded to the production environment of customer. But customer "using" in his environment only UI. Put business logic on the server side and make UI talks to the application server through services(WCF or Web API). Then you can have latest version for business logic and provide different UI for different .NET versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Stop linking the code files.*

Instead, start extracting the shared files into actual class libraries that target 3.5. If you're already sharing them between projects, then they must already compile with that version of the compiler. Remember, you can always reference a library built against an older version of the framework.

Stop the insanity. Will anyone actually know that you did the right thing and created class libraries instead? You say this is a new project, there's no reason to create a mess like this on day one.

Comment: I like where your going, but unfortunately I cannot change this as it is one of the corporate decisions I was saying I had to live with... In fact I like @Bart van Ingen Schenau 's answer but I guess technically you have the right answer.

Comment: Do you have influence over any sympathetic ears @Sebastien? Who actually made these "corporate" decisions? Ultimately, a corporation is still just a bunch of people.

Comment: I do not have much influence since I've been hired recently.

Answer (score 1):

If there are (expected to be) files that are specific for one of the supported platforms or features that intentionally behave differently on the different platforms, then you should definitely test those parts on both platforms.

Besides that, it is a question of effort versus risk if you want to test the rest on both platforms or just on one of them.

Comment: 'effort versus risk' the famous last words of every manager.

Answer (score 1):

As you know your solution will target at least two different platforms 3.5 and 4.5.2 you need to make sure all your test cases addresses both platforms.

If one or more tests are dependent on a specific platform, you'll have to make sure there is a similar test on the other platform.

Especially you need further test cases to make sure that code made towards 4.5.2 does not interfere with code made towards 3.5 and vice versa.

This is far from simple, it will take a lot of effort to make sure that you cover every difference between the two platforms.